# DOMException when trying to write to clipboard after a confirm

Tags: typescript, window, clipboard, confirm, email-client

I'm having the user confirm wether they want to copy a email address to their clipboard or not after/if they do not have a default email client.
It successfully detects if I do not have a default email client but gets stuck on document not being focused.
Full exception: Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Document is not focused.

I have tried using the window.focus() and following if-statement outside of the setTimeout(), in that case I do not get the previous mentioned exception but nothing is copied to the clipboard.
I have also tried using async and await on various places in the code without success.

My code below:

```js
verifyEmailHandler() {
      let t;

      window.addEventListener('blur', () => clearTimeout(t));
      let confirmed = false;
      t = setTimeout(() => {
        confirmed = confirm(
          `Email client could not be launched. You will have to manually mail this user. \nPress "OK" to copy "${this.userInfo.email}" to your clipboard.`
        );
        window.focus();

        if (confirmed) {
          navigator.clipboard.writeText(this.userInfo.email);
        }
      }, 500);
    },`
```

Comment: I just copy-pasted your code and it worked fine. however the browser asked me for permission to use the clipboard. Maybe that is your problem try to change the permissions on your browse

Comment: That's the weird part. If I put the `navigator.clipboard.writeText()` before the confirm box (and while the window/DOM is in focus) I get the text copied to my clipboard. @LucasA